# Relative link does not work with Tomcat 7.0.67

Tags: tomcat

Relative link does not work with Tomcat 7.0.65

Hi guys,

I was migrating the application from old server to new server.
For the web server on new server, I'm working with apache tomcat_7.0.67 and java version is 1.8.0_65.
The migration worked successfully, but there's something problem in new server when I click a link that I used to access.
So I check the element and here it is

> `<a href="./element2/element3" target="_blank">here</a>`

, it's totally same with the older one. With same source, in the older one it directed to http://10.245.251.13:8080/element1/element2/element3, but in the new one it directed to http://10.245.251.13:8080/element2/element3, it missed "element1" and it looks like the tomcat in new server cannot parse "./"

So is there any configuration that I miss?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: so you have *some element* that resolves to different URLs. Care to let us know the culprit, the *something*, that exposes this behaviour? It seems to have something to do with `./` as you mention this out of context in your question, but other than that I'm clueless about your problem

Comment: Sorry @Olaf, I just realize that html code did not show before in my post..

Answer (score 1):

It's not the server - rather the browser that constructs the URL. Monitor your browser's requests (e.g. with Firebug or any of its descendents in the browser of your least distrust). You'll figure out that sooner or later there's a request `GET /element2/element3`.

This might be because the [<base>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag is missing - or other metadata pointing the browser to the respective relative position.

Tomcat does not parse `./`, because in a new request it has no clue where `.` was because that other page has been loaded in an unrelated different request.

Comment: Hmm I forgot add the information that I use same browser to open the link from the old server and new server.

Comment: That doesn't matter: it's still the browser that constructs the URL. IMHO it's best to construct a fully qualified absolute URL - at least up to the server's root path, e.g. starting with / and not with a dot